# Can't $scope data after running method

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am building a small weather application, by using data from a weather API. I have to convert the temperature from kelvin to Celsius, and then use substring to get rid of all the decimals. However, sometimes the temperature is below 0 and even -10 Celsius, so i have to run through a for loop to make sure to get the same format every time (Max 1 decimal).

And now to my problem. I make an array that keeps all the temperatures in Celsius. Then i run through a loop to make sure to get the right format (-11.5, 1.9, 18.7....) Then i add it to a new array, and afterwards a json string. This whole thing works, but somehow i can't use $scope to send my data to the HTML file.

Any ideas of, what I am doing wrong?

```
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.forecast = data;
                    //Creates array with temperatures
                    var arrayTemp = [
                        data.list[0].temp.day-273.15,
                        data.list[1].temp.day-273.15,
                        data.list[2].temp.day-273.15,
                        data.list[3].temp.day-273.15,
                        data.list[4].temp.day-273.15,
                        data.list[5].temp.day-273.15,
                        data.list[6].temp.day-273.15
                    ];
                    //Function that takes array as parameter, and makes the right format
                    function add(array){
                        var newArray = [];
                        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            if (array[i] > 0) {
                                if (array[i] > 10) {
                                    var res = array[i].toString().substring(0, 4)
                                } else {
                                    var res = array[i].toString().substring(0, 3)
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (array[i] > -10) {
                                    var res = array[i].toString().substring(0, 4)
                                } else {
                                    var res = array[i].toString().substring(0, 5)
                                }
                            }
                            //Add data to new array
                            newArray.push(res);
                        }

                        //Creates json
                        var json = {"temps":{"one":newArray[0],"two":newArray[1],"three":newArray[2],"four":newArray[3],"five":newArray[4],"six":newArray[5],"seven":newArray[6]}};

                        return json;
                    }
                    var newJson = add(arrayTemp);
                    $scope.data = newJson;
                }).
```

Comment: I don't get it. Is it `$scope.forecast` or `$scope.data` you are binding to?

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion. It is $scope.data. - $scope.forecast is the origin json from the API

Comment: And `newJson` is generated correctly, right? Then we need to see how you are using it. Most likely it's a binding issue somewhere.

Comment: Yes. If i am running this function in a separate project, i will get this: { temps: 
   { one: '273.',
     two: '273.',
     three: '273.',
     four: '273.',
     five: '273.',
     six: '273.',
     seven: '273.' } }

Comment: Then please show us the controller/directive this scope belongs to.

Comment: I don't think its problem with the controller itself. I can scope the data from the first scope ($scope.forecast = data) to my HTML file. But not the second scope..

Comment: How is this not obvious? If scope.a works and x contains the correct data then scope.b = x should end up in a scope.b that "works". Thus the issue _has_ to be somewhere else.

Comment: Can you show us the output of following on your html `<div>{{forcast.list[0].temp.day}} | {{forecast.list[0].temp.day - 273.15}} | {{data.temps.one}}</div>`

Comment: I get this out: 281.78 | 8.629999999999995 | The last one is not shown

Comment: What does `{{data}}` output?

Comment: Uhm, nothing. In the controller 'data' is what i get back from the API. Then i am "renaming" it as forecast. So in my html i can call {{forecast}}.. EDIT: Oh, i am scoping data at the end of the mehod. But that does not show anything either.